# How to show diagrams in C# .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, diagram, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to show a diagram like this in C# .NET Windows Forms Application. I have a file with 2D data and every thing is alright. I just need an API to show a graphical diagram for  the user.

[Picture of my sample diagram http://upload.tehran98.com/images/qzluxti62q0xmjyizaet.jpg](http://upload.tehran98.com/images/qzluxti62q0xmjyizaet.jpg)

Comment: This is a shopping question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [MS Chart Control for Winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

[DynamicDataDisplay](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) is nice but targeting wpf. It is possible to use [wpf in winforms](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) but I have never done it.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's always [Telerik.](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/chartview.aspx) But it's not free. The [Microsoft Chart Contorls For Microsoft .NET](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) could be something.